# Ag-grid React CellMouseOut Event not being fired

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

**onCellMouseOut** event not being fired always.

I want to display some text on **hovering** of cells in the row. I am using Ag grid event call backs **onCellMouseOver** and **onCellMouseOut**. I am maintaining a variable which stores current row Index where mouse is present.I am redrawing the row when mouse enters any of its cells. The former event (**onCellMouseOver**) is being fired appropriately and but the later one(**onCellMouseOut**) is not being fired always on exiting the cells.

A working demo of my problem is present below:-

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/4lS8euZclar4i7j5

The text in second column is supposed to appear only when you hover on that particular row, and disappear when you move the mouse away from that row. Although some of the times it is behaving as expected but some of the times the **mouseExit** event is not being fired.
Other issue because of this is checkbox selection is not working since i'm redrawing the cells again.

Comment: Probably `this.gridApi.redrawRows` is causing your issue, if I remove that it console logs all the time correct result. Try alternate strategy like possibly adding/removing classname on the current node hovered